# Azure DevOps Extension - how to run?

Tags: html, azure-devops

I created a hello world Azure extension.  I followed Microsoft's directions from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?view=azure-devops.  Instead of showing someone's name I just changed it to hello world in the Html.  Then, I loaded it to the marketplace and then installed it into my organization.  At this point, I need to get the hello world to pop up based on clicking the save button in Azure DevOps on a ticket.  But, the Microsoft directions don't really tell you have to run the extension.  It just tells you how to build it and get it installed in your organization.  Once its installed, how would I get it to run based on a button click?

Answer (score 0):

In the vss-extension.json file, we can find the categories is Azure Repos, so you will find your extension in the azure repos page.
You can refer the doc [Required attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/manifest?view=azure-devops#required-attributes) to help you know more about this.